# How to Make Excel Range of cells as uneditable using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I build an Excel application using C# in my WPF application. In that Excel I created one **Header Row**. Now I want to make **Header row cells as uneditable** cells and it should **revert back to the previous value**. For that, I am using **Validation** for header row to satisfy this condition . When I am going to change the any cell in the Header row It will show an alert box. The Alert box icon is not fine and also its having some other buttons like Retry, Cancel and Help.

1) Now I want to know How to get that Alert Box by using some better format(Icon Should be an Information image and It Should have Retry and cancel button.No need for Help Button)  .

(or)

2) I dont want to show the alert box But the new modified value has to revert to the previous value. The cell has to uneditable.

(or)

3) Can we use lock the particular range of cells?

My Code for that Condition is:

```
public static void FormatAsHeader(this Range range, bool wrapContent)
{
 .
 .
range.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateCustom, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "\"\"");
}
```

Can any one please tell me the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do: `range.Locked = true;` and then call `Protect()` on your worksheet.

See [`Range.Locked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.locked%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [`WorkSheet.Protect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840611.aspx).

Comment: Fine. But In that function "FormatAsHeader" having Range only not worksheet. Bcoz I am using MVVM model thats why I called this function on my controller. So Here I dont have the active worksheet. Can we get the active worksheet by range?

Comment: @pst: Here I dont have my active worksheet in this class. Here I am having range only.

Comment: The Range has a `.Worksheet` property that points to the containing worksheet.

Comment: I have one doubt in this code. If I'll use the worksheet.Protect(), Can I edit other cells in the same worksheet except Header cells?

Comment: Within the Protect(), What I have to use?

Comment: You can set almost everything from Protect (see link above). You can block editing, formatting, etc specifically. The defaults on Protect (linked above) should lock everything, but you can set them as needed if you want something else. Before you protect it, you may need to make sure everything else in your spreadsheet is not locked as well (I know I've had cells locked but not protected by default but that might depend on version). You could select everything, unlock that range then lock your specific range. You'll need to play with it a bit and see how it works for you in your situation.